# How can I have the user click on the screen of my HTML5 video and be taken to a link in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, video-player

How can I have the user click on the screen of my HTML5 video and be taken to a link in a new window?
I've looked around and can't find much text on it. Basically similar function to what you get on YouTube etc. User clicks on video and taken to link in new window.

Using code like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I'd imagine it'd look something like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
<a href='http://www.google.com'> test link</a>
</video>
```

Comment: Do you want the video to even play on the current page?

Comment: Yes, but if the user clicks the screen bit, they are navigated to another page in a new window. Like an advertisement for a new movie, you watch and then at the end it may say click on me to be taken to our site.

Answer (score 0):

if i catch your problem right, this solution can help you

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
    </video>
    </a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bXrPL/

Comment: Your way works very well but is there a method which only makes the screen area (where movie is) rather than task bar too (pause,rewind etc)

Comment: Pity, but i don't know how to do it in simple way. Anyway, if you will not find better way of doing it, I recommend you to create your own controls. Here is an article about it: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/#scripting

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ysttd/

Rather than sticking the `<a>` tag inside `<video>`, wrap the `<a>` and the `<video>` tag inside a parent element:

```
<div class="videoContainer">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="http://snapshot.opera.com/resources/BigBuckBunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <a href='http://www.google.com'> test link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to place a `<video>` inside a link to achieve that.

However, since you have specified `controls` the video is *interactive content* so that is not allowed.

Instead, you can use JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('click', function () {
    open("http://example.com", "_blank");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as well:

```
<video width="320" height="240" onclick="window.open('http://google.com')" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
    <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```